# Excel/VBA Connecting to Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, excel, vba, oracle10g, excel-2007

I am writing an Excel 2007 macro in VBA that queries an Oracle database based on some user input. When I record a macro of the query, the macro uses ListObjects.Add. But I know there is also the QueryTables object, among other things. I am looking for an object that will make the hand-coding easiest, i.e. the code will be clean and concise, and make sense. Furthermore, I can't simply record a macro, because the query is variable - it is dependent on user input.

What is the best object (ListObjects, QueryTables, etc.) from the Excel Object Model Reference (in the MSDN Library) to use for this purpose? More generally, what is the best way to go about it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone ahead with QueryTables, which is documented in the MSDN Library under Excel Model Object Reference. It is clean, simple, and direct.